# Git - get the changes from master and put them on my branch

Tags: git

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b newBranch
...
git commit
git checkout master
```

Now, there are changes in master, and i want to move those changes to my newBranch.

What do i do, do i git rebase master? or git rebase newBranch? Or something else entirely?

(And why didn't git just make the naming conventions really obvious?)

Comment: What do you mean by "move those changes to my newBranch"? Merge?

Comment: idk you tell me

Comment: @tkausl i just want the stuff that is now in master - time has passed, in this example - and i want that stuff in my newBranch

Comment: Thats what a merge does.

Comment: @tkausl why does everyone talk about rebase then?

Comment: Rebase does something similar but produces a different history which may or may not be important. You shouldn't use rebase unless you know what it does and why you can't use merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b newBranch (creating new branch)
// do stuff
git add . 
git commit -m "your changes"

Now (go back to master and get the latest changes):
git checkout master
git pull origin master

Go back to your new created branch:
git checkout newBranch
git merge master (fix conflicts if there are any)
Now you have all the changes from master into your branch.
```

You can also use `git rebase` but here is an interesting article about why you shouldn't do that: https://medium.com/@fredrikmorken/why-you-should-stop-using-git-rebase-5552bee4fed1

Comment: you're a god-send. everytime i was using rebase i just kept getting merge errors - but using merge master? perfect. thanks!

Comment: @bharal merge errors/conflicts might occur by `git merge` as well, that's not the point between the two. The main difference is that `git merge` keeps your commit history as is whereas in `git rebase` you kinda re-write the commit history. It's up to you to decide which to use, **just make sure that - in case you use `git rebase` - you are the ONLY ONE using this branch** cause otherwise your action (rewriting commit history) will create a mess for the rest of the team working on the same branch ;)